# Update control's backcolor - check before update

Tags: c#, properties, controls, updates

In c# application, is the following code necessary for any performance advantage?

```
//update a control's background color or so
if (label1.BackColor != Color.Black)
    label1.BackColor = Color.Black;
```

Comment: performance advantage as compared to...?

Comment: Well I don't think it gives you a lot of performance advantage, but it can't hurt either :

Comment: You would have to weight the cost od the check (probably next to nothing at all) against the gain of (just __possibly__) avoiding the repaint. Do not worry, or if you really want to, watch the colors you set while you do it..

Comment: performance advantage compared to directly update the color: label1.BackColor = Color.Black while the backcolor is already the same as the color to be set.  I wonder if the dot net will do any optimization to avoid unnecessary repaint.